# JQuery popup hiding but not closing

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, popup

I want to display an onload youtube video JQuery popup in my home page.

Looking into the internet and "mixing" some codes, I have the result bellow.

It seems to do what I was trying to do, but the "Close" button is not working.

When I press "Close", the popup hides but continues playing backwards.

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you!

THE CODE:

```
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”&gt;
<head>
<title>jQuery Show Popup on Page Load</title>

<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

/* video settings come here */
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '350',
width: '600',
videoId: 'L8ARwB3CihA',
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady
}
});
}
/* Autoplay when the dialog opens */
function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.playVideo();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
var overlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"></div>');
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});


$('.x').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});

$('.click').click(function(){
overlay.show();
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
$('.popup').show();
return false;
});
});
</script>



<script type=’text/javascript’>
$(function(){
var overlay = $(‘<div id=”overlay”></div>’);
overlay.show();
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
$(‘.popup’).show();
$(‘.close’).click(function(){
$(‘.popup’).pauseVideo();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='popup'>
<div class='content'>
<div id='player'></div>
<p><a href='' class='close'>Fechar</a></p>
<br/>
<br/>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't need to see your css and please format your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks Louis! I took out the css, but what do you mean by "format your code correctly"? Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I haven't tested it myself

```
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.popup').remove(); // Change hide() to remove()
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});
```